# SPF block when uing webform

Tags: spf

I have configured my domains SPF as follow:

```
v=spf1 a mx:mx01.glesys.se mx:mx02.glesys.se a:smtp.bredband2.com ip4:188.40.202.41 ip4:174.136.101.66 ip4:66.228.34.169 -all
```

The two MX from glesys is my hosting service MX,
bredband2.com is my ISP and the IP's is my servers.

Now to the question.
Sometimes, when I am using a webform to send a message, I get a bouncback telling me that due to the SPF, the email has been blocked. Something like this:

```
<admin@receiving-domain.se>: host mx-cluster-b2.one.com[195.47.247.195] said: 554 5.7.1
<admin@receiving-domain.se>: Recipient address rejected: Please see
http://www.openspf.org/why.html?sender=r.hill%40gate5.se&ip=91.198.169.19&receiver=mx-c.one.com
(in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

Does it mean that something is wrong in my SPF?
Or simply that the webform is badly configured (ie. using my address as the sender instead of having it as reply-to?)

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the IP address of the server which is sending the email is in the SPF record. In This case you would have to add 91.198.169.19 to the SPF entry.

To avoid issues like this it's best to use the smtp server (which you use in your email programm) to send the emails. Make sure you authenticate if that is necessary.